# What is the Lagrange Interpolation polynomial of $1/{(x-1)}$?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

So what is the value of

$$L[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n; \; 1/{(x-1)}]=\text{?}$$

I tried writing a Mathematica program to compute it, but I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: Did you try using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)?  What do you get?

Comment: I got a very long and awful result.......

Comment: If $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are arbitrary, that's to be expected.